# Sound probelm in applications, but hardware is fine

Tags: 18.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have a unsolved sound problem in ubuntu 18.04. It seems as if the hardware works fine since the speakers make a sound when I draw and drop the volume slider. Although, no sound works in any of the applications such as Spotify or Firefix. I also tried the "test sound"-function under settings but it doesn't make any sound.

Comment: Are you sure the applications are not muted? Try watching a video or something in firefox and go to your system sound settings and then click on the applications tab and see if there is a volume there that is maybe muted.

Answer (score 1):

Check the audio settings or try running `alsa force-reload`:

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugs all the same, I can't tell you how many times I plugged the speakers in the wrong hole on the backside of the PC.

In 18.04 you are most likely running PulseAudio, bring up the System Activity and do a search for PulseAudio. If you find PulseAudio, open a terminal window and type;

> $ pavucontrol

Oddly enough sometimes it is not installed with PulseAudio.

> $ sudo apt install pavucontrol

If you don't find PulseAudio is up and running at all, you are probably running straight ALSA.  You need to open a terminal and type;

> $ alsamixer

at the prompt. Use arrows up and down to set volume, arrows left and right to move from slider to slider.  Esc key will exit the program.